# Problem when doing Anova on categorical variable in R

Tags: r, statistics, anova

I have two variables: `decsorgs2` and `regionfactor` (which is a factored "region")

```
freq(decsorgs2)
 decsorgs2 
            Frequency Percent
 0 Disagree       365   53.76
 1 Agree          314   46.24
 Total            679  100.00

freq(regionfactor)
regionfactor 
        Frequency Percent
 1            12   1.767
 2            82  12.077
 3           128  18.851
 4            64   9.426
 5           138  20.324
 6            43   6.333
 7            53   7.806
 8            57   8.395
 9           102  15.022
 Total       679 100.000
```

I am trying to do an anova with `aov()`.

```
  aov(decsorgs2~regionfactor)
  Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
   NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'
  In addition: Warning message:
 In model.response(mf, "numeric") : NAs introduced by coercion
```

What are these errors? I don't understand any of these terms

EDIT: Ok, I did a hail-mary random attempt and recoded decsorgs2.

Initially I had:

> decsorgs2 = recode(DECSORGS, "4:5='0 Disagree'; 1:2='1 Agree'")

Now I used:

> decsorgs2 = recode(DECSORGS, "4:5=0; 1:2=1")

It seemed to work. But why? Why does `decsorgs2` have to be numerical, if the purpose of factoring the variable region was to make it be read as categorical? How do I know which one has to be numerical and which categorical?

Comment: May be you need to convert `Inf`, `NaN` values (if present) to `NA`.

Comment: Thanks, but there are no NA, Inf values. We can see that in the freq() outputs.

Comment: Please show some example dataset that produce the error.  It was just a guess from the error you showed.

Comment: Should you not do chi-square test for 2 categorical variables variables rather than anova?

Answer (score 1):

`aov` needs a continuous response variable. You are passing a `character` variable and it is coerced to `numeric`:

```
y <- c("0 Disagree", "1 Agree")
as.numeric(y)
#[1] NA NA
#Warning message:
#NAs introduced by coercion 

y <- c("0", "1")
as.numeric(y)
#[1] 0 1
```

You need to reconsider your statistical methodology.

Comment: Thanks, but why is that the case? Why did I have to make region into a character variable? For ANOVA, is the dependent variable supposed to be numeric or character?